# Disable then re-enable button after AJAX Response

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So I'm trying to disable a button while javascript is processing, then re-enable it when the javascript is done. The code below works in every browser I've tried except for IE7. In IE7 it just seems to ignore the disable and re-enable and looks like it's still enabled the whole time. So how can I get the correct behavior in IE7?

```
    <script>
      function doSomething()
      {
        document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
        ...
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        response = xmlhttp.responseText();

        if (response != "false")
        {
          document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;
        }
        ...
      }
    </script>
    <form onsubmit="doSomething(); return false;">
      <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Do Stuff"/>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Normal toggle works fine for me in IE 7.0.5730.13: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/sQU3x/show/

Comment: Yes, if I only do 1 or the other in a function it works, but if I do both in the same function like I showed, it just seems to ignore the disable part.

Comment: The "do stuff and put results in result div"-part is probably so fast (or async) that it re-enables the button befores re-rendering. What happens in the "do stuf ..."-part? Ajax?

Comment: Yes it's an ajax call, it does take around 1 second, so it is plenty of time to see the difference, and is visible in firefox.

Comment: Nope. The Ajax call takes 1 second, BUT is async, so what actually happens between the disable & enable takes only .5ms. All that happens is firing the request. The rest (and response!) is async. What you'll need to do is put the re-enable in the ajax response handler (which is executed after ~ a second).

Comment: I put the re-enable code in a if(response != "false") block so it shouldn't execute until after the AJAX returns, but it still doesn't work in IE7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a redraw issue with IE7, so it wasn't redrawing until everything executed. So after more research and many attempts at getting IE to redraw when I wanted it to this was what finally worked, it's really hokey and I hope to find a better way to do it, but it works for now.

```
<script>
  function doSomething()
  {
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(doSomething2(), 1);
    return false;
  }

  function doSomething2()
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    response = xmlhttp.responseText();
    document.getElementById("results).innerHtml = response;
    setTimeout(doSomething3(), 1);
    return false;
  }

  function doSomething3()
    document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;
    return false;
  }
</script>
<form onsubmit="doSomething(); return false;">
  <input type="submit" id="myButton" value="Do Stuff"/>
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` is not a true/false toggle. If you want to enable something after it has been disabled you can remove the `disabled` attribute completely.

To set: `document.getElementById("myButton").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");`

To clear: `document.getElementById("myButton").removeAttribute("disabled");`

Comment: `disabled` is a true/false toggle. In IE7 too. http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/sQU3x/show/

Comment: Yes, if I only do 1 or the other in a function it works, but if I do both in the same function like I showed above, it just seems to ignore the disable part.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the `disabled = false` part in the ajax response handler:

```
function doSomething() {
  var btn = document.getElementById("myButton");
  btn.disabled = true;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, false);
  xhr.send(null);
  var response = xhr.responseText;

  // Test this stuff!
  alert(response);

  btn.disabled = false;

  // Test more!
  alert(btn.disabled);
}
```

Comment: Here's what I have now, but it still doesn't work

`xmlhttp=newXMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
response = xmlhttp.responseText;
if (response != "false)
  {document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = "";}`

Comment: Can you post the full `doSomething()` function, so I can tell you where to put what?

Comment: updated my original post to give a better idea of what I have right now

Comment: Aah. Your request is not async (3rd arg in `xhr.open()`). Then you don't need a callback function. **However** `xhr.responseText` is not a function, so change that to how I've updated my answer.

Comment: That does work with the alerts, it doesn't work without them. It appears to be a redraw issue with IE7 (and 6) and I've posted the only thing that has successfully caused a redraw so far.

Comment: Could you post the working code online somewhere? I'm very, very curious. In a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be best, but anywhere I can look.